# alias with parameters

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

If there is any possibility to use the parameters in zsh aliases?  Something like this:

```
 alias ssh_nokia="ssh root@<ip_parameter>"
```

Usage:

```
 ssh_nokia 192.168.1.2
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your particular case edit ~/.ssh/config (See Dave's answer below), or use:

```
alias ssh_nokia='ssh -l root'
```

Generally

```
ssh_nokia() {
    ssh root@"$@"
}
```

is equivalent to alias (will produce `ssh root@1stparam 2ndparam 3rdparam …`).

Comment: What was there before Michael edited the response?  Perhaps something easier to understand than the shortcut "$*"?

Comment: @smallsense, at first there was simple `$1`, because I wasn't sure how does "$*" behave when glued together with literal part `root@`.

Comment: Squashing a command or other subsequent argument into the hostname is an obvious Wrong Thing. Perhaps instead you want `"$@"` instead of `"$*"` here?

Comment: I'd use `ssh -l root "$@"` in the function. This way, the host name isn't required to be the first argument to `ssh_nokia`, and overriding the user id is still an option (by using `other@host` or repeating the `-l` option in the arguments to the function).

Comment: @chepner, I don't think using `ssh -l` in a function is any better than using alias, though not any worse either. The reason why I used `root@` in a function is to illustrate the possibility of doing what the OP initially asked for. That is not to say I disagree, just explaining myself. Or better my 6 years ago self ;-) (time flies!)

Answer (score 9):

I would use up `~/.ssh/config` to create an alias for a particular connection, like so:

```
Host=anyoldname
Hostname=[hostname or ip address]
User=root
```

Then you can:

```
$ ssh anyoldname
```

More info:

```
$ man ssh_config
```

Comment: IIRC, you need to use space instead of `=` in ssh config, other than that, although it doesn't exactly answers the question about shell, it is definitely worth upvoting.

Comment: Equals sign works just fine on Mac, and on FreeBSD.
"Configuration options may be separated by whitespace or optional whitespace and exactly one ‘=’; the latter format is useful to avoid the need to quote whitespace when specifying configuration options using the ssh, scp, and sftp −o option."